# Tooltip for widget inside a QGraphicsProxyWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qgraphicsscene

I've got a `QGraphicsScene` in which I added `QPushButtons` inside `QGraphicsProxyWidgets`. Is there a way to display tooltips for those buttons? The `setToolTip` works but nothing appear when I hover on the buttons. Do I need to specify some flag on the `QGraphicsScene/View` ?

A simplified version of the button creation code :

```
class Button(QPushButton):

def __init__(self, scene):

    super(Button, self).__init__()

    self.proxy = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
    self.proxy.setWidget(self)
    scene.addItem(self.proxy)

    self.setToolTip("tooltip")
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the tooltip on the proxy didn't work either, sadly, but a coworker looked a bit further in my code and found why neither proxy nor button's tooltip worked : I had set an override on the `QGraphicsView mouseMoveEvent`, which might have broken the hover event. Adding a...

```
else :
    super(CustomGraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

...at the end of the `mouseMoveEvent` override solved the problem. Sorry for the mistake, and thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the tooltip to the `QGraphicsProxyWidget`.

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me :)")
    proxy.setWidget(button)
    proxy.setToolTip("Proxy toolTip")
    scene.addItem(proxy)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]